# Tabulator - unique id available?

Tags: tabulator

I'm wondering whether tabulator assigns (and keeps tabs) of a unique ID of the data it reads into the table rows.

Example, when you read a JSON array into tabulator:

[`[
    {id:10, name:"Billy Bob", age:"12", gender:"male", height:1, col:"red", dob:"", cheese:1},
    {id:27, name:"Mary May", age:"1", gender:"female", height:2, col:"blue", dob:"14/05/1982", cheese:true},
    {id:34, name:"Christine Lobowski", age:"42", height:0, col:"green", dob:"22/05/1982", cheese:"true"},
    {id:42, name:"Brendon Philips", age:"125", gender:"male", height:1, col:"orange", dob:"01/08/1980"},
    {id:59, name:"Margret Marmajuke", age:"16", gender:"female", height:5, col:"yellow", dob:"31/01/1999"},
,
]`

would it assign unique keys 0 - 4 for these lines automatically?

The reason I'm asking is the following: I'm trying to use tabulator as a generic CRUD interface to a database for table-editing in mySQL. I have created a Class associated with the webbage (or a form on that page,) which holds all the relevant information retrieved from the database via php.

One of the properties of that Class is an array with all the relevant data records, and I would like to keep that Class in sync with the table in tabulator. I could, of course use, the table records primary key  which is part of the payload data ("id" in above example) to do that, but I would like to create a bit more of a generic approach and use a unique numeric key, based on what ever data is held in the Class.

Any thoughts or help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't assign an id (afaik) but you can specify any unique property in the data as an `index`.
Maybe that will help?

From the [docs](http://www.tabulator.info/docs/4.5/data):

> **Row Index**
>
> A unique index value should be present for each row of data if you
>   want to be able to programatically alter that data at a later point,
>   this should be either numeric or a string. By default Tabulator will
>   look for this value in the **id** field for the data. If you wish to use a different field as the index, set this using the **index** option parameter.

```
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    index:"age", //set the index field to the "age" field.
});
```

Comment: I understand, I can use a "custom" unique index... I was hoping to be able to avoid that, since my js Class already holds a numbered array of all the payload data ... and I wanted to be able to sync the tabulator table - after editing - back to that Class by recordnumber.

Comment: You many be misunderstanding – you **can** use an existing "ID" – you just need to tell `Tabulator` which one to use (as above): `index: "age"`

Comment: Hello spring. Thanks for jumping in. I understand, that I can use an existing unique "ID" and how to do that. The thing is, I do not want to do that, since I want to make the CRUD form independent (or agnostic) of the underlying data structure.   For this reason, I'm looking for a generic "unique ID" that creates a link between the loaded data and the data displayed in the table. This unique ID needs to "survive", any manipulations the user would do in the table (like sorting, filtering, editing, etc. -- deleting and adding records is a separate issue to be dealt with).

Comment: I don’t believe Tabulator maintains any sort of id internally. This is why it requires you to provide a unique id, if you want to do any programmatic editing. There isn’t anything preventing you from creating a global variable that you increment and using that as your id. Although, I’m not sure I see why you wouldn’t just use the data’s primary key.